# CakePHPのfind条件にORを設定

Tags: php, cakephp

CentOS 6.6
PHP 5.4.41 (cli)
cakephp 2.7.1

CakePHPのfind条件にORを設定
下記のコード1で検索を行うと問題なく動きます

コード1

```
$conditions['OR'] = array('Sample.test_id' => array(1,2));
$p_Sample = $this->paginate('Sample',$conditions);
```

or条件を可変にするため下記のコード2で実行すると
Sample.test_id=1の条件のみの結果となりカンマ以降が検索されません。
コード2

```
$con='1,2';
$conditions['OR'] = array('Sample.test_id' => array($con));
$p_Sample = $this->paginate('Sample',$conditions);
```

原因は何でしょうか？
ご教授のほどよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コード2は検索条件として`1,2`という文字列1個の配列を渡している、つまり

$conditions['OR'] = array('Sample.test_id' => array('1,2'));

になるので、

```
WHERE Sample.test_id => '1,2';
```

になって、おそらくtest_idは整数型だと思うので

```
WHERE Sample.test_id = 1;
```

と型変換されてるんでしょう。

```
$con=array(1,2);
$conditions['OR'] = array('Sample.test_id' => $con);
```

なら意図通りになると思います。

Comment: $con=array(1,2);
ではうまくいきませんでしたが下記のように変えるとうまくいきました
$con=array(intval(1),intval(2));
ヒントになりました
ありがとうございました